# Is there a way to search for elements that don't have a particular tagged value in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

The model search feature is an excellent tool for finding elements throughout a given project. Is there the ability to search for elements that do not have a particular tagged value. For example I want to find all elements that don't have the tagged value property Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in search for it, and the Search Builder does not allow you to create such a filter. But you could write an SQL search for it.